# How to link/bind files to folders on the file system

Tags: c#, file, filesystems, directory

I want to bind a file to a folder so that when the file is moved/copied/deleted the folder is also automatically moved/copied/deleted along with the file (Similar to how html files are linked to the folder containing their resources)

At the moment this behaviour is activated only for html files and their corresponding "htmlFilename_files" folders. Is there a way to register another file extension for such behavior? Or is there a hack or feature that provides similar behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even for HTML this behavior is specific to Explorer.

The problem is that there's no "copy" operation on filesystem level (and Move operation is different from what you see in user mode).

Technically you can create a filesystem filter driver and track RenameOrMove and Delete operations on some file, then perform some operation with the directory. But this won't work for copy which is a sequence of "read" + "write" operations and you would have hard time matching reads and writes (but, well, I can think of some ways to track copying using filter driver as well). You can create a filter driver yourself, but this requires C programming and special knowledge. You can write a driver yourself ([read MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx)) or use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product (it provides a pre-created driver and .NET API for integration with your software).

If data file is yours, it makes sense to keep all files in one virtual container - this can be MHT file (HTML + supplementary files are combined into MHT by Internet Explorer), ZIP archive or SolFS storage (SolFS is our virtual file system product). Then there's only one file for the user to manage and your application has all files inside.

If you need to let external applications access files in the container, then the virtual disk can be created - such disk will expose contents of the container. Contents of any container can be exposed as a virtual disk using now-dead Dokan or our Callback File System product.